# find if files in one directory recursively exists in another directory recursively in linux bash and print exists or not exists

Tags: recursive, file-compare

find if files in one directory recursively exists in another directory recursively in linux bash and print exists or not exists

lets say you have

- `pth1/dirA/file1` `pth1/dirA/DirB/file2`  and
- `pth2/dirA/file1` `pth2/dirA/DirB/file3`

I want a report that

```
file1 exists 
files2 dont exist in pth2
files3 dont exist in pth1
```

i have found that code that works for current level for both directories, but i cant make it work recursively [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577193/check-if-same-file-exists-in-another-directory-using-bash)

```
pth1="/mntA/newpics";
pth2="/mntB/oldpics";
for file in "${pth1}"/*; do
    if [[ -f "${pth2}/${file##*/}" ]]; then
       echo "$file exists";
    fi
done
```

How I can do it to work recursively on both paths?

Comment: It would be helpful with larger example set size

Comment: Given `pth1/dirA/file1`, are you wanting to see if there is a file called `file1` _anywhere at all_ underneath your `pth2/dirA`? Or must it be at the same relative place? What about comparing file contents, or are you just interested in the names?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with another method. I find all files in one directory, strip their path, then I can save the results in two different files and compare them with meld or other program, or I can compare finds directly with meld.

Note that I sort files and choose only unique files and not duplicates in results. Also, I am interested only in files that their filename ends in "jpg" extension.

```
pth1="/mnt/oldfiles";
pth2="/mnt/newfiles";
```

and then

```
(find "${pth1}"/ -exec basename {} \; | grep "jpg$" | sort | uniq )  > a.txt;
(find "${pth2}"/ -exec basename {} \; | grep "jpg$" | sort | uniq )  > b.txt;
meld a.txt b.txt
```

OR diretly

```
meld <(find "${pth1}"/ -exec basename {} \; | grep "jpg$" | sort | uniq )  <(find "${pth2}"/ -exec basename {} \; | grep "jpg$" | sort | uniq )
```

UPDATE:
if one directory is much larger than other, the direct command dont work (MILD opens without both commands finish).

Comment: And what if there are files with same names, but different contents, or same contents, but different names?

Comment: at this case, i know very well the content, same name same content.

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly clear what you want, but I think this will do it. This command compares all files under `/path/1` to those under `/path/2`, checking for existence and equality.

```
diff --brief --recursive /path/1 /path/2
```

Worked example

```
# Create some files
mkdir -p 1/{x,y} 2/{x,z}
touch 1/{x,y}/file1
date | tee 2/x/file1 >2/z/date

# Show what we have
tree 1 2
1
├── x
│   └── file1
└── y
    └── file1
2
├── x
│   └── file1
└── z
    └── date
4 directories, 4 files

# Compare the two directory trees
diff --brief --recursive 1 2
Files 1/x/file1 and 2/x/file1 differ
Only in 1: y
Only in 2: z
```